# What does // operator mean in Julia?

Tags: julia

say I have this code:

```
a = 4//2
```

This returns me "2//1"

```
b = 4//3
```

This returns me "4//3"

I understand that it is returning the value of a and b in simplest form. But what then? I thought that this operator returns the value of division in integer form, taking away the reminder. But it does not seem this is what it is doing.

I actually have this code:

```
x=Fun(identity,0..4π)
d=domain(x)
B=[ldirichlet(d),lneumann(d),rneumann(d)]
D=Derivative(d)
κ = 0.33205733621519630   
u0 = (1//2) * κ * x^2
```

I wanted to know what (1//2) here is. From what I had thought earlier, this should have been equal to zero, but that is not what is required here. Can please someone clarify what is happening here and how does the // operator works?

Comment: `2//3` is a *rational number*, I suppose you might call the `//` operator a constructor.

Comment: This is correct, you should post it as an answer.

Comment: You can see it's not just echoing back the input by trying values such as `5//10`, which will yield `1//2` as the result.  It reduces the ratio by eliminating common divisors of the numerator and denominator.

Comment: This is the second question this week about // where the original poster thought it was the "integer division" operator. There may be a tutorial out there miswording something. OP, do you mind sharing if you saw this operator in some tutorial, and if so in which one?

Comment: This looks like translated Sympy code somehow? `//` in Python and Julia is quite different.

Comment: It's just because `//` is integer division in python. It's natural that people who are used to python assume it's the same operator in Julia.

Comment: Ah! That makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Julia when you do not know something the first thing to do is to press `?` to go to the help REPL mode represented by `help?>` prompt. After pressing `?` type the command you are curious about:

```
help?> //
search: //

  //(num, den)

  Divide two integers or rational numbers, giving a Rational result.

  Examples
  ≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡≡

  julia> 3 // 5
  3//5

  julia> (3 // 5) // (2 // 1)
  3//10
```

One more additional usefull way to check what is going on in Julia is to use `dump`:

```
julia> dump(2//4)
Rational{Int64}
  num: Int64 1
  den: Int64 2
```

Finally, following the comment by @DNF it is worth noting that there is the integer division operator `÷` (and a corresponding function `div`) that computes x/y, truncated to an integer.:

```
julia> 13 ÷ 4
3
```

Comment: Maybe add how to do integer division with `div`?

Comment: I remember writing about that on SO two days ago :-) However as you wish - done :-)

Comment: Remember DRY: Do Repeat Yourself ;)